# Acceleration acquired by a metallic ball in a fluid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

> A metallic ball of density $4.9gcm^{-3}$ is thrown in a bucket full of water.What is the acceleration acquired by the ball?(ignore all factors except gravity and resistance given by water,ball and take $g=9.8ms^{-2}$)

The thing is that I could solve the problem assuming that the ball was accelerating but how do you know that it must be accelerating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is nonsense. For a start “acceleration acquired” doesn’t mean anything.

Given what they have told you, they want you to answer $\frac{4.9-1}{4.9}$ times 9.8 and they have even arranged the numbers so that you don’t need a calculator.

But unless you have a bucket of *non-viscous* water, none of this will happen. The terminal velocity of the ball falling through the water will be very slow, and in fact if you drop the ball from a height of more than a couple of centimetres, it will be going at more than the terminal velocity in water by the time it actually hits the water, so it will decelerate, not accelerate.

There is real world truth and there is “exam truth”. To be a scientist, you need to know the first. To pass exams, you need to know both.